# Insert the output of Matlab Java Package to array

Tags: java, matlab, netbeans, matlab-deployment, javabuilders

I've build MATLAB java package using Matlab Compiler in Matlab R2016a and I want to call it to my Netbeans project. I look [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/gs/create-a-java-application-with-matlab-code.html) tutorial and I build this code:

```
        MWNumericArray data1=null;
        MWNumericArray data2=null;
        Object[] result = null;
        Class1 lse = null;
        try {
            data1=new MWNumericArray(A, MWClassID.DOUBLE);
            data2=new MWNumericArray(target, MWClassID.DOUBLE);
            lse = new Class1();
            result = lse.rekursif_lse(1, data1,data2);
            //T = result;
        }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception! "+e.toString());}
        finally
        {
         MWArray.disposeArray(data1);
         MWArray.disposeArray(data2);
         MWArray.disposeArray(result);
         lse.dispose();
        }
```

where:

rekursif_lse is the file (.m) that I have been package to java (.jar) package

A is a matrix with 60x20 dimension

```
double A[][]=new double[60][20];
```

target is a matrix with 60x1 dimension

```
double target[][]=new double[60][1];
```

T is the output that I hope from rekursif_lse

```
double T[][]=new double[2][20];
```

Now, how to insert the " result " to the " T "?
I've tried

```
T = result;
```

but it didn't work.
Thankyou.

Comment: "Did you time travel? because the last version that Mathworks released is MATLAB 9.2"

Comment: What is the size of result? You may try two (nested) for loops.

Comment: The size of "result" is matrix with 2x20 which is same with "T"

Comment: But, " result " is output of the rekursif_lse that I've been packaged to java.
I confused about how to put the values of "result" to the "T" array